# values within ssms generated xml tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssms

I have the following code to generate an xml output.

```
select
   [FirstName] as 'SubscriberName/FirstName',
   [Middle] as 'SubscriberName/MiddleName',
   LastName as 'SubscriberName/LastName',
   '123 fake street' as 'Address/Address1'
from chp_work_area.dbo.Students1099hc
FOR XML PATH('SubscriberInformation'), ROOT('Test')
```

The output of this is the xml below, and is accurate.

```
<Test>
  <SubscriberInformation>
    <SubscriberName>
      <FirstName>BOB</FirstName>
      <MiddleName>G</MiddleName>
      <LastName>CHOI</LastName>
    </SubscriberName>
    <Address>
      <Address1>123 fake street</Address1>
    </Address>
  </SubscriberInformation>
  <SubscriberInformation>
    <SubscriberName>
      <FirstName>MOLLY</FirstName>
      <MiddleName>G</MiddleName>
      <LastName>MORTY</LastName>
    </SubscriberName>
    <Address>
      <Address1>123 fake street</Address1>
    </Address>
  </SubscriberInformation>
</Test>
```

The last piece that I need is for subscriber information to list which record it is inside the tag, so that it reads as follows.

```
    <Test>
    <SubscriberInformation docID="Person001">
    <SubscriberName>
        <FirstName>BOB</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>G</MiddleName>
        <LastName>CHOI</LastName>
    </SubscriberName>
    <Address>
        <Address1>123 fake street</Address1>
    </Address>
    </SubscriberInformation>
    <SubscriberInformation docID="Person002">
    <SubscriberName>
        <FirstName>MOLLY</FirstName>
        <MiddleName>G</MiddleName>
        <LastName>MORTY</LastName>
    </SubscriberName>
    <Address>
        <Address1>123 fake street</Address1>
    </Address>
    </SubscriberInformation>
</Test>
```

Comment: use "@docID" as an alias... you'll have to do some work to it. Test by select [FirstName] as "@docID" and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FirstName],[Middle],[LastName] ASC) AS "@docID",
   [FirstName] as 'SubscriberName/FirstName',
   [Middle] as 'SubscriberName/MiddleName',
   LastName as 'SubscriberName/LastName',
   '123 fake street' as 'Address/Address1'
from chp_work_area.dbo.Students1099hc
FOR XML PATH('SubscriberInformation'), ROOT('Test')
```

Comment: You didn't say what the "Person001", "Person002" field was, so replace the docID field with that.

Comment: There is no person001 field. I just wanted incremental values.